# SData Integration with Sage Accounts 50, 2010 release

Tags: sage-line-50, sdata

Sage says that SData is available in Accounts 50, 2010 release onwards.

I have this version installed, but when I go to [http://myserver.com:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/$schema](http://myserver.com:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/%24schema) or even [http://myserver.com:5493/sdata/accounts50/SDO/-/$schema](http://myserver.com:5493/sdata/accounts50/SDO/-/%24schema), (and any other SData URL) I get the following ApplicationNotFound reply:

```
<diagnosis xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:sdata="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" 
xmlns:sme="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/sme/2007" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/http/2008/1">
  <sdata:severity>error</sdata:severity>
  <sdata:sdataCode>ApplicationNotFound</sdata:sdataCode>
  <sdata:applicationCode/>
  <sdata:message>
    Unable to locate a handler to process the request 'accounts50/GCRM/-/$schema'
  </sdata:message>
  <sdata:stackTrace/>
  <sdata:payloadPath/>
</diagnosis>
```

Is there a particular URL that I need to use SData?
From the services panel, I see that I am already running the Sage SData service (it was installed along with the Sage software itself).

Comment: You need to use SDO? Does GCRM work?

Comment: I've tried several methods, neither of the above works on Accounts 50, 2010. Although you do find an enable button and actually see the service running, you cannot access it.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path? i.e. using the company guid instead of the dash in the url.

Comment: Not sure whether I did - but I tried several options before I moved to Accounts 50, 2013.  Now it works as expected.

Comment: @KingCronus It's not support below Accounts 2012, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit misleading but as mentioned on the SData Forum -

> #### From the [SData Forum](http://sdata.sage.com/SDataForum/) - [Sage 50 sdata error](http://sdata.sage.com/SDataForum/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=66#197)
> Posted: 11 January 2012 05:20:03
>
> Although ***Accounts 2010 and 2011 are SData compliant
> this is only in place for internal use to support the ACT integration
> and Sage Mobile applications***. There is no support for use by 3rd party
> developers for these releases and no current plans to introduce
> support I'm afraid.
>
> Support for 3rd party developer use of Sdata in the Accounts 2012
> release is currently in beta and only open to members of the Sage
> Developers Programe. Just to be clear, the reason why support is
> currently in beta is not to do with the quality of the Sdata feeds,
> which are fully functional and tested, but rather to do with us
> needing time to produce toolset support (e.g. Visual Studio plugins),
> code samples, knowledge base articles, training programmes and other
> SDK and support documentation.

So if you want to use SData you'll need Sage Accounts 50 2012 +

Comment: In fact the only way I proceeded with SData was by updating the version of Sage.